# what is the most efficient way to preallocate unordered_map<string, vector<uint8_t>>?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory

I work with an unordered_map<string, vector<uint8_t>>.
I can know the number of pairs, and the size of all the vectors<uint8_t> are all the same and are known at all times. I was wondering if I could enhance the performance by allocating all the needed memory, before inserting elements.
From what I understand I can preallocate the number of string "key/slots" with .reserve().
But is there a way to allocate all the memory that the unordered_map will need from the beginning?

Comment: You can't "prealllocate" the vectors for non-existent keys, but I suppose you can move the vectors into the map upon creating the map entry. .

Comment: Each vector owns its own memory, so you need to talk to each vector to tell them they need X amount of memory.

Comment: Are you using C++17 or later?  `std::unordered_map::extract` would allow you to pre-allocate map nodes with dummy values that can later be given correct values and re-inserted in your unordered_map.

Comment: `std::unordered_multimap<std::string, uint8_t>`  may be a better container for your use-case. I expect it to better handle the allocation. `std::string` also perform some allocations but this is fine with short strings due to the short string optimization (avoiding allocations). The same is true for the vectors currently (`reserve` do not reserve each vector) I think STL allocators are a perfect use-case for what you want.

Comment: if you have vectors of know sizes and they are all the same, then don't you actually have a  value type of std::array<uint8_t,N>  (instead of std::vector<uint8t) ? And if you're going to have M keys, You can preallocate contiguous memory and map your keys to pointers into that memory. Final step wrap it all up in a class.

Comment: Do you know how many _Key_ strings your final map will hold and how many values there will be in each of the mapped `vector<uint8_t>`s?

Comment: I am using C++17.
Yes, I know how many Key strings I have, and the vector size is unique and constant.

Comment: Nope, there's no such thing. Nothing can be preallocated here.

Comment: If the vectors size is constant, you can allocate them in one big chunk (In a `shared_ptr<uint8_t[]>` is probably the safest and easiest) and have them be `std::span`s into that one allocation. You can also reserve the size when you create each vector. Or you can use a custom linear allocator, but I couldn't find a good implementation. Some example code of how you are creating and populating this map currently would be useful in giving better suggestions.

Comment: In order to pre-allocate memory, try `std::pmr::unordered_map`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of such a datastructure.
Instead of storing key,value pairs directly,
this datastructure first stores data in an array (preallocated),
then stores the key + index into the array into the map.

When retrieving data, the map is used to lookup the index in the array
for the given key and returns that.

Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/zulZwWh3j

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// a preallocated map

template<typename key_t, std::size_t number_of_keys_v, typename value_t>
class preallocated_map final
{
public:
    // key value pairs to put into the map
    struct kv_t
    {
        key_t key;
        value_t value;
    };

    template<std::size_t N>
    preallocated_map(const kv_t(&entries)[N]) :
        m_size{ 0ul }
    {
        for (const auto& entry : entries)
        {
            // store a value in the next unused free slot
            m_values[m_size] = entry.value;

            // they map will now hold an index into the m_values array for the key
            m_index_map.insert({ entry.key,m_size });

            // increase stored size
            m_size++;
        }
    }

    const auto& at(const key_t& key)
    {
        return m_values[m_index_map.at(key)];
    }
        
    ~preallocated_map() = default;


private:
    // memory to store values in 
    std::array <value_t, number_of_keys_v> m_values;

    // mapping of key to an index into the array of values.
    std::unordered_map<key_t, std::size_t> m_index_map;

    // number of values in the map
    std::size_t m_size;
};



int main()
{
    preallocated_map<std::string, 4, std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>> map
    { {
        {"one",{'1','2','3','4'}},
        {"two",{'2','4','6','8'}}
    } };

    auto values = map.at("two");
    for (const auto& value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```